# Simple past or past perfect?- she ------- me doing something that she had forbidden me to do

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

This is the last part of a pretty long paragraph:

> " ... To my horror I realized that my grandmother had got up out of bed and was coming towards the study. Two second later she opened the door. I will never forget the awful feeling of shame that she ........ (catch) me doing something that she had forbidden me to do."

What is the proper tense to complete the gap: simple past or past perfect? Why?

Comment: I didn't give the down-vote, but  you may want to add your takes on this question.

Comment: @Cardinal: I first used the simple past form but the key says that the past perfect form of the verb is correct. Even though it seems okay, I can't understand the reason why it should be in the past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is the time relationship between the experience of shame and the event of being caught.  If the shame occurs while being caught, then simple past is the best choice.  If the shame occurs while later reflecting on being caught, then past perfect would be better.

If the order of events is

1. Grandmother forbids something
2. Grandmother catches the speaker in the act and the speaker feels shame
3. The speaker relates the experience

the sentence should be:
"When she walked in, I felt shame wash over me because she **caught** me doing something she had forbidden me to do."

If the order of events is

1. Grandmother forbids something
2. Grandmother catches the speaker in the act
3. The speaker thinks about it and feels shame
4. The speaker relates the experience

the sentence should be:
"For the next several weeks, every time I thought about her walking in, I felt ashamed because she **had caught** me doing something she had forbidden me to do."

Comment: Thanks for your answer but which tense fills the gap in my question best? In fact, the key has offered only one option, i.e. past perfect but I don't see the reason why. How can it be explained?

Answer (score 0):

"I will never forget the awful feeling of shame that she ........ (catch) me doing something that she had forbidden me to do."

'Catch' should be in the simple past because it happened after 'forbidden' which is in the past perfect.  The past perfect is used when there is an action x which happens before an action y and y is in the simple past.